# Bottom page border not being printed on Legal sized pages with an HP LaserJet

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, printer, hp-laserjet, border

I've been facing this problem for the past few days. My printer is an HP LaserJet M1005 MFP. Currently I am using Word 2013. Whenever I try to print a "Legal" sized page with borders, it prints everything except the bottom border.

Here is an image of my problem:

[image: 1]

I can print "A4" sized pages with all borders with no issue however, so how do I achieve the same for "Legal" sized pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I find solution for this problem

The border looks fine, it is exactly as I wanted it to look. However, when I go to Print Preview, I can see that the bottom border will be missing if I print.

To solve that, I am going to make one change from the default setting.

Go to the Format menu and select Borders and Shading .

In the Borders and Shading window, select Page Border .

At the bottom right portion of this window there is a button labeled Options.

Click on the Options button. In the Borders and Shading Options window you should see a Measure from box which, by default, is set to Edge of page .

Click on the down pointing arrow and select Text .

Click on OK to get back to the Borders and Shading window where you will click OK again.

I found this solution at [here](http://www.internet4classrooms.com/msword_more_borders.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem by following the steps given below:

- open word>design >page borders
- go to options...
- instead of measure from edge of page ...... change to text
- put the following values in margin

  `*top= 10 pt`
   `*bottom =10 pt`
   `*left= 10 pt`
   `*right =10 pt`

This would solve the border not printing problem